# How to start and stop a process in a java program while waiting other method start and stops every 3 seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

hello i have a method that i want to call every 3 seconds to doing some calculations and after that the result will going on to a new method and doing its work while the first method it stops

```
 Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                System.out.println("Hello  world " + checkFileToReceive);
                      here is the calculation of the **intnumbOfChunks** which is used
in the main program

            }
        };

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and here i have the main program doing something. 
how i can stop and start the main programm while waiting the helloRunnavle finish? 
the main programm is

```
for (int i = 0; i < intnumbOfChunks; i++) {

            fileToClaim = "";
            fileToClaim = "bigbang.mp4";
            fileToClaim = String.format("%s.part%06d", fileToClaim, i);

            if (i==0){
                checkFileToReceive = fileToClaim;
                System.out.println("checkFileToReceive "+fileToClaim);
            }

            if (i%2==0){
                fileparts.add(fileToClaim);
//              System.out.println("fileToClaim "+fileToClaim);
            }else {
                fileparts1.add(fileToClaim);
//              System.out.println("fileToClaim1 "+fileToClaim);
            }   

        }
```

Comment: how i can pass the intnumbOfChunks from thread to the main process?

Comment: in the process i want to measure the speed of two servers. and after calculating it, to see what is the defference and put it to the lists so to know how many chunks i need to download from every server and how many chunks i can do. but because the speed of the network changing, i need to calculate the speed every 30 seconds! so to change dinamic the lists!

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 0; i < intnumbOfChunks; i++) {

```
        fileToClaim = "";
        fileToClaim = "bigbang.mp4";
        fileToClaim = String.format("%s.part%06d", fileToClaim, i);

        if (i==0){
            checkFileToReceive = fileToClaim;
            System.out.println("checkFileToReceive "+fileToClaim);
        }

        if (i%2==0){
            fileparts.add(fileToClaim);
        }else {
            fileparts1.add(fileToClaim);
        }  

        Thread.sleep(3000); 

    }
```

Comment: this will stop all the excecution after it finished! i need to stop when the first process is running. and runs when the first is stoped!